# the semi-final (singular) meaning the team's advancement level in the tournament

Tags: grammatical-number, definite-articles, abstract-nouns

If you meant to convey that they won their quarter-final game and are now going to play at the semi-final **level** (**in a single-elimination tournament**), you would often say 'The team advanced to the semi-final**s**.'

I'm curious to know if you would possibly also use the singular, regarding 'semi-final' as meaning **the level**, as in:

- The team advanced to the semi-final.

(Note: There is only one match at each level for a given team)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the stage is always referred to as the *semifinals* (plural). This applies in your scenario, and also in events like races where there are more than two contestants at a time. The plural is used because the semifinal stage always contains more than one match; if there were only one event it would be the final. The contestant has reached the stage in the event at which these matches (the semifinals) are contested.

The noun *semifinal* (singular) always refers to a single match. It would be common to say something like "X advanced to a semifinal against Y". To say "X advanced to the semifinal" would be to imply that there was only a single semifinal, and that is not the case in your scenario.

Comment: So you would say 'the semifinals' even if they only play one semi-final game to go up to the final match. Right, Peter?

Comment: Correct. There are two matches even though they only play in one of them.

Comment: Just to make sure I've given you my query correctly, I ask you if you would say 'They advanced to the semifinals' and only that, when they at the next level play only one game before the final game. Thanks, Peter!

Comment: If the team has won through the quarter-finals and they need to play and win a single semifinal before competing in the final, I would indeed say that they had advanced to the semifinals.

Answer (score 0):

*semi-final* is an adjective used as a synonym for its noun (*game* or *match*)

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/semifinal)
> *semi-final*:
> noun [ C usually plural ]
> (informal semi)
>
> one of the two games that are played to decide who will take part in the final game of a competition:
> *Who's in the semifinals?*
> *She's the youngest player ever to get through to/advance to a semifinal.*

With this definition, a *semi-final* is one of the games played within the set of two semi-final games that are played to determine who advances to the final game.

We may therefore say:
*"The team advanced to the semi-finals, where they played their own semi-final against ... "*
"*Two other teams played the other semi-final.*"

Comment: Cambridge is not universally correct here. There are competitions (e.g. the Australian Football League) where the name *semifinal*  is used for different games in a finals series. Note also that in race events there may be more than 2 semifinals.